# Python Pandas joining Dataframes of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use the data from two dataframes, say frame_a and frame_b, wich are indexed by timestamps. frame_a contains only one column and is shorter than frame_b (all indices of frame_a are included in frame_b's indices). My code in structure looks something like the following.

```
dataframe = DataFrame(index=frame_a.index)
dataframe.join(frame_a["a"])
dataframe.join(frame_b["b"])
```

Now 'dataframe' is indexed by frame_a's index and should have taken only those values from frame_b["b"] where the indices correspond to those of dataframe. I now extract the data with iterrows() and use it to create a new DataFrame 'returnframe':

```
timestamps = []
results = []
for row_idx, row in enumerate(dataframe.iterrows()):
        try:                    ## note that row_idx is integer and index is here a datetime
            index,data = row
            rowData = data.tolist()

            a = rowData[1]
            b = rowData[2]
            if a < b:
                b = b+1
            results.append(b)
            timestamps.append(b.index[row_idx])
        except:
            pass
returnframe = DataFrame(index=timestamps) # this frame is even shorter than frame_a
returnframe["results"] = results
```

I need the try statement to filter some NaNs... 1st problem: I couldnt figure out how to use 'apply' or something instead of the for loop. Does anyone know a more efficient way? Second problem:

```
returnframe.join(frame_b["something"])
```

does not behave as I'd expected. I need to add frame_b's data to my returnframe where both frames' indices (timestamps) are equal. But 'join' appears to add some rows somewhere inbetween (maybe due to duplicate indices??). It's important for my other functions that the length of returnframe is not changed by the latter addition of data.

For completeness here my entire function (df_input and df_signals are function parameters). It takes signals (integers) and adjusts holdings, funds and valuation according to the signaled 'buy' or 'sell'. :

```
def calculatePerformance(self, df_input, df_signals, closei=3, changei=11, printResults=True):
    funds_array = []
    holdings_array = []
    valuation_array = []
    percChange_array = []
    date_array = []
    type_array = []
    signal_array = []
    type = df_input["type"][0]

    funds = df_input["close"][0]*8
    holdings = 0
    valuation = funds
    percChange = 0

    merged = pd.DataFrame(index=df_signals.index)
    merged = merged.join(df_signals["type"])
    merged = merged.join(df_input["close"])
    merged = merged.join(df_signals["signal"])

    prices = np.array([price for index, price in merged["close"].iteritems()])
    signals = np.array([signal for index, signal in merged["signal"].iteritems()])

    for row_idx, row in enumerate(merged.iterrows()):
        try:                    ## note that row_idx is integer and index is here a datetime
            index,data = row
            rowData = data.tolist()

            price = rowData[1]         
            signal = np.int(rowData[2])
            if isinstance(signal, np.int) and signal != 0:
                if signal > 0 and (signal*price) > funds :
                    signal=0
                elif signal < 0 and (holdings == 0 or (holdings+signal) < 0):
                    signal = holdings

                funds -= signal*price
                holdings += signal
                valuation = funds + holdings*price
                percChange = (valuation - valuation_array[0])/valuation_array[0]*100.

            type_array.append(type)
            date_array.append(index)
            signal_array.append(df_signals["signal"][index])

            funds_array.append(funds)
            holdings_array.append(holdings)
            valuation_array.append(valuation)
            percChange_array.append(percChange)



        except:
            pass


    # build and return the performance df of this stock
    df_performance = pd.DataFrame(index=date_array)        
    df_performance["type"] = type_array

    df_performance["signal"] = signal_array
    ## i would like to use the following line, but it wont work. i want to use it that way to eventually eliminate the need for the above for loop
    #df_performance["signal"] = df_signals["signal"]

    df_performance["funds"] = funds_array
    df_performance["holdings"] = holdings_array
    df_performance["valuation"] = valuation_array
    df_performance["percChange"] = percChange_array

return df_performance
```